# Bad Credentials when authenticating with active directory LDAP with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, ldap, spring-security-ldap

I am trying to use Spring Security to perform authentication and authorization in front of my REST controller, which is also secured with SSL. The code I have is mostly derived from the example at https://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap/

The application works correctly using the embedded LDAP server as shown in the link. I connect to my home page https://localhost:9000/training/trackerHome and log in with the user "ben" and password "benspassword" (as specified in the link). Everything is fine.

But when I update my properties and try to connect to a real LDAP server, I just keep getting errors that say "Bad Credentials" on the login page. The error log looks like:

```
training-server_1    | 2020-11-10 17:07:23.728 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8443-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 1 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
training-server_1    | 2020-11-10 17:07:23.728 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8443-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 2 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
training-server_1    | 2020-11-10 17:07:23.729 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8443-exec-2] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
training-server_1    | 2020-11-10 17:07:23.729 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8443-exec-2] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@1b6d157. A new one will be created.
training-server_1    | 2020-11-10 17:07:23.730 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8443-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 3 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
training-server_1    | 2020-11-10 17:07:23.730 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8443-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 4 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
training-server_1    | 2020-11-10 17:07:23.740 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8443-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 5 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
training-server_1    | 2020-11-10 17:07:23.740 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8443-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/logout'
training-server_1    | 2020-11-10 17:07:23.741 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8443-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 6 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
training-server_1    | 2020-11-10 17:07:23.741 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8443-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/login'
training-server_1    | 2020-11-10 17:07:23.742 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8443-exec-2] w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Request is to process authentication
training-server_1    | 2020-11-10 17:07:23.743 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8443-exec-2] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider
training-server_1    | 2020-11-10 17:07:23.744 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8443-exec-2] o.s.s.l.a.LdapAuthenticationProvider     : **Processing authentication request for user: john.doe**
training-server_1    | 2020-11-10 17:07:23.784 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8443-exec-2] w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.**BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials**
training-server_1    |
training-server_1    | org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials
training-server_1    |  at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider.doAuthentication(LdapAuthenticationProvider.java:197) ~[spring-security-ldap-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.1.RELEASE]
training-server_1    |  at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:85) ~[spring-security-ldap-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.1.RELEASE]
training-server_1    |  at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:174) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.1.RELEASE]
training-server_1    |  at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:199) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.1.RELEASE]
training-server_1    |  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:94) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.1.RELEASE]
training-server_1    |  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.1.RELEASE]
training-server_1    |  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.1.RELEASE]
training-server_1    |  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.1.RELEASE]
training-server_1    |  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.1.RELEASE]
training-server_1    |  at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:124) [spring-security-web-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.1.RELEASE]
training-server_1    |  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
training-server_1    |  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.1.RELEASE]
training-server_1    |  at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) [spring-security-web-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.1.RELEASE]
training-server_1    |  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
training-server_1    |  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.1.RELEASE]
training-server_1    |  at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.1.RELEASE]
training-server_1    |  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.1.RELEASE]
training-server_1    |  at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.1.RELEASE]
training-server_1    |  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
training-server_1    |  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.1.RELEASE]
training-server_1    |  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) [spring-security-web-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.1.RELEASE]
training-server_1    |  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) [spring-security-web-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.1.RELEASE]
training-server_1    |  at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) [spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
training-server_1    |  at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) [spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
training-server_1    |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar!/:9.0.12]
training-server_1    |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar!/:9.0.12]
training-server_1    |  at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
training-server_1    |  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
training-server_1    |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar!/:9.0.12]
training-server_1    |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar!/:9.0.12]
training-server_1    |  at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) [spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
training-server_1    |  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
training-server_1    |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar!/:9.0.12]
training-server_1    |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar!/:9.0.12]
training-server_1    |  at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
training-server_1    |  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
training-server_1    |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar!/:9.0.12]
training-server_1    |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar!/:9.0.12]
training-server_1    |  at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
training-server_1    |  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
training-server_1    |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar!/:9.0.12]
training-server_1    |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar!/:9.0.12]
training-server_1    |  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar!/:9.0.12]
training-server_1    |  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar!/:9.0.12]
training-server_1    |  at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar!/:9.0.12]
training-server_1    |  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar!/:9.0.12]
training-server_1    |  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar!/:9.0.12]
training-server_1    |  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar!/:9.0.12]
training-server_1    |  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar!/:9.0.12]
training-server_1    |  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar!/:9.0.12]
training-server_1    |  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar!/:9.0.12]
training-server_1    |  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:770) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar!/:9.0.12]
training-server_1    |  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar!/:9.0.12]
training-server_1    |  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar!/:9.0.12]
training-server_1    |  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_212]
training-server_1    |  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_212]
training-server_1    |  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar!/:9.0.12]
training-server_1    |  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_212]
training-server_1    |
training-server_1    | 2020-11-10 17:07:23.785 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8443-exec-2] w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Updated SecurityContextHolder to contain null Authentication
training-server_1    | 2020-11-10 17:07:23.786 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8443-exec-2] w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Delegating to authentication failure handler org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler@63d9b403
training-server_1    | 2020-11-10 17:07:23.786 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8443-exec-2] .a.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler : Redirecting to /login?error
training-server_1    | 2020-11-10 17:07:23.786 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8443-exec-2] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to '/login?error'
training-server_1    | 2020-11-10 17:07:23.787 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8443-exec-2] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
training-server_1    | 2020-11-10 17:07:23.787 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8443-exec-2] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Part of my confusion is the handling of the password. I'm not sure what to specify, if anything, for the password encoder? I fear I may be encoding an already encoded password. I have tried all of the possible types of password encoder, and also not using a password encoder at all. Still get the Bad Credentials error.

application.properties when using embedded LDAP server:

```
ldap.server.url=ldap://localhost:8389/dc=springframework,dc=org
spring.ldap.username=
spring.ldap.password=
ldap.password.encoder=bcrypt
ldap.user.dn.pattern="uid={0},ou=people"
ldap.group.search.base="ou=groups"


# Configuration of Spring's embedded LDAP server (used for development and testing)
spring.ldap.embedded.ldif=classpath:test-server.ldif
spring.ldap.embedded.port=8389
spring.ldap.embedded.base-dn=dc=springframework,dc=org
```

test-server.ldif excerpt showing definition of user "ben"

```
dn: uid=ben,ou=people,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
cn: Ben Alex
sn: Alex
uid: ben
userPassword: $2a$10$c6bSeWPhg06xB1lvmaWNNe4NROmZiSpYhlocU/98HNr2MhIOiSt36
```

application.properties when using actual LDAP server:

```
ldap.server.url=ldap://125.126.127.128:389/DC=MY-LAB,DC=MY-COMPANY,dc=local
spring.ldap.username=MY-Lab\manager.doe
spring.ldap.password=validpassword
ldap.password.encoder=none
ldap.user.dn.pattern="uid={0},ou=MY-LAB"
ldap.group.search.base="ou=MY-LAB"
```

Actual LDAP Server structure:

```
DC=MY-LAB,DC=MY-COMPANY,DC=local[125.126.127.128]
    OU=Domain Controllers
    OU=MY-LAB
        OU=Users
            OU=Outside Users
                CN=Manager Doe
                      (User principal name = manager.doe)
                CN=John Doe
                      (User principal name = john.doe)
```

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSecurityConfig.class);

  @Value("${ldap.server.url}")
  private String ldapServerUrl;

  @Value("${spring.ldap.username}")
  private String ldapManagerDn;

  @Value("${spring.ldap.password}")
  private String ldapManagerPassword;

  @Value("${ldap.password.encoder}")
  private String ldapPasswordEncoder;

  @Value("${ldap.user.dn.pattern}")
  private String ldapUserDnPattern;

  @Value("${ldap.group.search.base}")
  private String ldapGroupSearchBase;

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and().formLogin();
  }


  @Override
  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
  public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    switch(ldapPasswordEncoder) {
      case "none":
        passwordEncoder = null;
        break;
      case "bcrypt":
        passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        break;
      case "ldap":
        passwordEncoder = new LdapShaPasswordEncoder();
        break;
      case "MD4":
        passwordEncoder = new Md4PasswordEncoder();
        break;
      case "MD5":
        passwordEncoder = new MessageDigestPasswordEncoder("MD5");
        break;
      case "pbkdf2":
        passwordEncoder = new Pbkdf2PasswordEncoder();
        break;
      case "scrypt":
        passwordEncoder = new SCryptPasswordEncoder();
        break;
      case "SHA-1":
        passwordEncoder = new MessageDigestPasswordEncoder("SHA-1");
        break;
      case "SHA-256":
        passwordEncoder = new MessageDigestPasswordEncoder("SHA-256");
        break;
      case "sha256":
        passwordEncoder = new StandardPasswordEncoder();
        break;
      default:
        log.warn("password encoder property not specified. Using default value.");
        passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    if(passwordEncoder != null) {
      auth.ldapAuthentication().userDnPatterns(ldapUserDnPattern).groupSearchBase(ldapGroupSearchBase).contextSource().url(
          ldapServerUrl).managerDn(ldapManagerDn).managerPassword(ldapManagerPassword).and().passwordCompare().passwordEncoder(
              passwordEncoder).passwordAttribute("userPassword");
    } else {
      
auth.ldapAuthentication().userDnPatterns(ldapUserDnPattern).groupSearchBase(ldapGroupSearchBase).contextSource().url(
          ldapServerUrl).managerDn(ldapManagerDn).managerPassword(ldapManagerPassword).and().passwordCompare().passwordAttribute(
              "userPassword");
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas what I've done wrong to make the authentication with the real LDAP server always return "Bad Credentials"?

Answer (score 0):

What password encoder in your actual LDAP? You sure that ldap.password.encoder is equal to it. for example, if it is sha1, the value of ldap.password.encoder will be SHA-1. And if you want not to encode your password. please fix it as below. Hope it useful to you.

```
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder;

    switch(ldapPasswordEncoder) {
      case "none":
        passwordEncoder = NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
        break;
     ....
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the NoOpPasswordEncoder! I fixed the code as you showed above. Still the same error though. I'm not sure what method the LDAP server uses, and nobody I ask seems to know. I have tried each of the encoding methods, but still keep getting the "Bad Credentials". Specifying the managerDn and managerPassword values seems to work, because when I leave them blank, I get an error about not being able to bind. Still not sure what is wrong yet.

Comment: if you use openldap, I remember that you can install a tool manage its password via https://ltb-project.org/. With it you can config password encode way. Or by a win tool called [ldapadmin](http://www.ldapadmin.org/download/ldapadmin.html), you can query it too. It is another topic:)

Comment: I find a [guide](https://www.javachinna.com/2020/06/01/secure-spring-boot-rest-api-using-ldap-authentication-and-authorization-with-database/) . Maybe it helpful to you.